# Strange... What does [::5,0] mean

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I found a webpage which explaining how to use `set_xticks` and . `set_xticklabels`.

And they set `set_xticks` and 'set_xticklabels' as following...

```
ax.set_xticks(xx[::5,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(times[::5])
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::5])
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::5])
```

What does  `[::5,0]`  exactly mean..

I don't have any idea.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a numpy array, the notation`[::5,6]` means to take the 6th column for that array and then in the 6th column, every 5th row starting at the first row till the last row.

Example -

```
In [12]: n = np.arange(100000)
In [17]: n.shape = (500,200)

In [18]: n[::1,2]
Out[18]:
array([    2,   202,   402,   602,   802,  1002,  1202,  1402,  1602,
        1802,  2002,  2202,  2402,  2602,  2802,  3002,  3202,  3402,
        3602,  3802,  4002,  4202,  4402,  4602,  4802,  .....])

In [19]: n[::5,2]
Out[19]:
array([    2,  1002,  2002,  3002,  4002,  5002,  6002,  ...])
```

Reference on numpy array slicing [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) , if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of python slicing, as described here:

https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

and 'advanced slicing', which is a further extension that works with numpy arrays, as documented here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

You probably want to skim through both a few times before it makes sense, although it's relatively straightforward. The answer by Anand S Kumar above explains the specific case you're asking about.